# Take screenshot of webpage using URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Can somebody guide me on how to take screenshot of the webpage using URL in Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: Could you please show some sample code on how to accomplish using an iframe

Comment: It did not show exactly how we are taking screenshot.

Comment: Actually, i am trying to save that screenshot as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a screenshot api.

Check here:
https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-website-screenshot-capture-API

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not sufficient to accomplish my requirement. Actually, i have to capture screenshot of my browser webpage, containing an openlayers map and save as pdf using javascript. (Just like how window.print does). Please let me know if you have any idea on this.